# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I got an error,sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked .I wrote index.py

```
def index():
    user = User.query.get()

    session["user"] = {
        "id": id
        }

    db.session.commit() #1
    if user is None:
        db.session.add("None")
        db.session.commit()

    item = Item.query.filter_by(id=3).first()
    return render_template('index.html', item=item)
```

and I wrote a db connection codes, `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:////Users/xoxo/Downloads/test.db'` .I give permision 777 to test.db but same error happens.And I delete #1 db.session.commit() but same error happens.What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?